# NGINX: how to block access to all files inside some directories

Tags: nginx

I have different files inside three different directories.

I'd like to block access to all files inside those (also block directory listing).

This way, I'd block, for example:

- /a/b/file
- /a/c/file
- /a/d/file

Whatever the file extension...

This is what I am trying:

```
location /a/(b|c|d) {
    allow 1.2.3.4; #IP
    deny all;
    return 403;
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `~` in your location config - without it means literal prefix matching, while you're attempting to use regex syntax.

```
location ~ /a/(b|c|d) {
```

Comment: Is the allow 1.2.3.4; #IP in the right position? Should it come after "deny all;" and "return 403"?

Comment: Yes, the order is right: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule